# UILayoutGuide height is changed after pop back on iOS 7, but iOS 8 is fine

Tags: ios

I have my home view controller embedded in UINavigationController. The navigationBar height is 44.

I am using auto layout, and at first, the UILayoutGuide height constraint is 64 (44+20(status bar)). everything is fine.

Now I implemented `UINavigationControllerDelegate` with custom push and pop animators.

on iOS 7,

If I push a my view controller and pop back with this custom push and pop animations, when I pop back to my home view controller, I found that the same UILayoutGuide is changed to 20, instead of 64.

However, on iOS 8, no code change, but everything works fine. UILayoutGuide is still 64.

I don't touch `UILayoutGuide` or `translucent` property, so they are default values.

I am quite confused how to fix this issue. Please help.

[image: 64]
[image: 20]